# GTK+ update appears to have messed up my application fonts

Tags: fonts, gtk

A few hours ago I installed a set of updates including GTK+ and I've noticed that my application menu fonts now look unsightly.

For example Netbeans

[image]

And Pinta

[image]

How can I revert back to the nicer looking fonts?

---

Accordint to `/var/log/apt/history.log` this is the last update I did before my fonts got messed up

```
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1740'
Upgrade: 
libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-java-common:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-base:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libreoffice-style-oxygen:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
google-chrome-stable:amd64 (64.0.3282.186-1, 65.0.3325.146-1),
libreoffice-kde:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5),
libpq5:amd64 (9.6.7-0ubuntu0.17.10, 9.6.8-0ubuntu0.17.10),
python3-uno:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-style-galaxy:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
ure:amd64 (5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.10+LibO5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 2:102.10+LibO5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
uno-libs3:amd64 (5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-style-tango:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-base-drivers:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5), 
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:amd64 (1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.4, 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Result! ... Well, sort of.

I backed up and then cleared `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and all fonts and menus now look pretty decent apart from some Netbeans menus. For example although the Team menu looks nice

[image]

The profile menu next to it looks awful. The problem appears to be the grayed out menus

[image]

BTW here's my old `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. The new one is currently blank.

```
include "/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
style "user-font"
{
    font_name="Noto Sans Regular"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"
gtk-font-name="Noto Sans Regular 10"
gtk-theme-name="Breeze"
gtk-icon-theme-name="breeze"
gtk-fallback-icon-theme="gnome"
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-button-images=1
```